# "Lunch" vs. "dinner" vs. "supper" — times and meanings?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns, dialects

I've seen cases where a noon-time meal is referred to as *dinner*, and the evening meal is called *supper*. There's also *lunch* around noon followed by *dinner* in the evening. Is there a particular difference between *dinner* and *supper*, or a circumstance where *lunch* becomes *dinner*?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

*Dinner* is considered to be the "main" or largest meal of the day. Whether it takes place at noon or in the evening is mostly a cultural thing. For instance, many people who grew up in the American South and/or on farms traditionally ate larger meals at noontime to give them the strength to keep working through the afternoon.

*Supper* is more specifically a lighter evening meal. Rooted in the word "to sup", it comes, again, from farming traditions — many farming families would have a pot of soup cooking throughout the day, and would eat it in the evening — specifically, they would "sup" the soup.

*Lunch* is almost the midday equivalent of *supper* — it's also a lighter and less formal meal than Dinner, but is used specifically when referring to a midday meal. So whether you use *lunch/dinner* or *dinner/supper* is heavily determined by when your culture traditionally has its largest meal.

*Much Later Edit*: I happened across [this article](http://www.wideopeneats.com/supper-vs-dinner/) discussing the agricultural roots of midday dinner and evening supper, just to add a bit more to the conversation.

Comment: Is this BrE? In my version of AmE lang/culture (pretty mainstream) whatever the size of the meal, 'lunch' is midday and 'dinner' or 'supper' is in the evening.

Comment: There's actually quite a bit of variation in different regions of the US. As I said, it's quite common to hear Dinner as the noontime meal in many areas of the American South. I've noticed that there's even a split in Texas where some regions use Lunch/Dinner and others use Dinner/Supper.

These differences have tended to mix up and get confused as people from different regions have mixed, and I've noticed "lunch" used for noonday meals much more unilaterally by today's young generations.

Comment: @Mitch: As an American, I'd mostly agree with Matthias that "lunch" refers to a noon-time meal and "supper" to an evening meal regardless of size, while "dinner" specifically refers to a larger or more formal meal. That said, people often use "dinner" to refer to an evening meal regardless of the size. I think the usage is a little ambiguous there. PS I've lived most of my life in Ohio and Michigan, maybe the usage is different in other parts of the country.

Comment: @jay: what you said sounds to me more like what -I- said rather than matthias. I say: Lunch = midday (any size)  supper or dinner = evening (any size), but sometimes dinner is a big special meal instead of linch or supper, like Sunday dinner or Thanksgiving dinner. When a kid we only used supper but now only dinner.

Comment: My grandfather (a farmer in NE Oklahoma) would regularly refer to a large *midday* meal as "supper".

Comment: Instead of saying "they would 'sup' the soup", I'd say that *supper* came from the French *souper* (which is both a verb and a noun). (Actually from Old French *soper*, it seems.)

Comment: @Drew Well, according to the New Oxford American (the source I used when answering above), *supper* derives directly from *to sup*, which is derived from the Old French *super* (to suck, sip), which I would take to be the predecessor of the modern French *souper*. Looking at Wiktionary, however, I do see the sourcing for *soper*, though I don't see a specific citation for that. *To sup* seems to have quite complicated dual etymologies on Wiktionary, so the full histories might be a bit too entangled to know for certain.

Comment: Links are notorious for rotting. Three years from now that link could be worthless, so why not say the name of the article, and include a relevant snippet?

Comment: I grew up with Dinner/Supper, but have conceded to clarifying by using Lunch/Supper. It is just more explicit.

Answer (score 41):

Harvard's [Dialect Survey](http://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/q_96.html) had the question, "What is the distinction between dinner and supper?" Here's the geographic distribution of their results from 10,661 American respondents:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: That link needs to be in this site's 'tool box' (along with the other dictionaries and etymonline and such).

Comment: In terms of those maps: http://xkcd.com/1138/ is obligatory

Comment: @Amory: Touché.

Comment: @Amory yes, the first thought that came to my mind, before i saw your comment :)

Comment: @Amory: Thank you. I was looking to make the same point.  And to point out that I see little in the way of a trend or takeaway from the figure posted here: each of the maps seems to be essentially the same relative distribution.

Comment: @Drew Not quite. It shows, for instance, that not using _supper_ at all is fairly evenly spread out (relative to population) throughout the country, while only using _supper_ is all but unknown on the West coast. So _supper_, all things being equal, is more of an Eastern than a Western word, while _dinner_ is ubiquitous.

Comment: If I had the dataset, I could normalize the weight by population concentration

Comment: The link to the survey has expired.

Answer (score 24):

In working-class families in the North of England, dinner was traditionally the noon-time meal, and there is an afternoon or evening meal called tea. However, this is changing to some extent as people move about and some try to sound more "Southern". (English usage in the South of England, or sometimes, more particularly the South-East, is generally taken to be "correct" English, as in this case.)

Comment: A funny article on the topic in question, which might provide deeper insight into the cultural differences involved. http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/8223453.stm

Comment: When I went to Yorkshire last year in a weekend trip, I heard for the first time people referring to the noon-time meal as dinner and also to dessert as pudding ("what's for pudding?")

Comment: Yeah, when at school, they were school dinners and we had dinner ladies.

Comment: It would be school dinners or packed lunch at our school... and we had dinner bids (as in "biddies")

Comment: We had school dinners and dinner ladies, but packed lunches, which makes little sense.

Comment: It makes sense because "dinner" is what you call it when you make an effort, whereas a sandwich in a box is merely "lunch". But it's important to be aware of the inconsistencies. Some people who typically call their midday meal "dinner" would, on a day when they have a light midday meal, call it "lunch" and call their evening meal "dinner". But others would stick to their typical usage regardless of the size of the meal. IIRC at my school it was "school dinners", "packed lunches", but both were eaten during a scheduled time called "lunch break". Other schools would call it "dinner break".

Comment: Same as @sweeneyrod - dinner ladies (or dinner people, if you want to be more progressive!) and school dinner but packed lunches. We used to say dinner and tea, but I think my mum wanted to try and make herself sound more middle class so we changed to lunch and dinner. I still call a meal at 5pm or so "teatime", because also being from a working class Manchester family, we didn't eat as late as we do now, so there was no need to differentiate tea vs evening dinner

Comment: So, symbolically, you're not supposed to eat anything after having afternoon tea?

Comment: This is why I now use *Lunch* and *Tea* exclusively

Answer (score 23):

In AmE/culture:

- 'lunch' is the midday meal (11:30am-1:30pm), however large it is (if you're eating something around that time, and you don't eat something bigger around that time, that was your lunch). If you eat your midday meal at 3pm, that's kind of a late lunch, but it wouldn't be called anything else. That is, in AmE, 'lunch' = midday meal; a midday meal is never called dinner or supper (but see the exception below).
- 'dinner' or 'supper' is the evening meal 5-7pm, or if later than that, more likely to be called a 'late dinner' or 'late supper'. 'supper' is not as common a term for the evening meal in AmE (my family used to call it that when I was a kid but I have rarely heard anybody else use it). So there is not much difference between dinner and supper (in AmE), except...
- A midday or rather main meal on a Sunday, is sometimes called 'Sunday dinner' (never 'Sunday lunch') and is more likely to occur later in the afternoon, anywhere from noon to 4pm (well, OK, any time from noon to 8pm). There is nothing called 'Sunday supper', (dinner has a higher register feel to it than supper).

Just to note, in AmE/culture: there is no such thing as 'tea' as a meal (it just refers to the drink, not to any kind of cultural event as in BrE/culture). The evening meal, whether dinner or supper, is usually the biggest, most special meal of the day. 'Brunch' (usually Sunday brunch) is a big late morning/midday meal (skipping breakfast) that I think culturally came about because of having the first meal on a Sunday after church service; how or if that interferes with Sunday dinner I don't know - having both in one day would be excessive. Maybe Sunday dinner is if you have to spend the time after church preparing the meal, and brunch is if you go out afterwards.

Anyway, that's only mainstream AmE/culture. Off to Easter dinner...hm...that would be a Sunday dinner on Easter I guess.

Comment: +1; this is dead on for where I grew up. "Brunch" usually occurred when there was a major time discrepancy between waking up in the morning. The early risers would eat breakfast than join the later risers for brunch.

Comment: Interesting statement about Sunday main meals... there are very similar circumstances in most UK households in my experience, but "Sunday Lunch" is an acceptable and in my opinion preferred description.  However a similarly prepared Christmas Day meal eaten at the same time (mid-afternoo) would never be "Christmas Lunch". This would be "Christmas Dinner".

Comment: @Mitch I am bound to say that your overview of the Great Debate in AmE/culture is one of the more enlightening here. I must temper my observation with one caveat: we must not forget that culture, socioeconomic status, class-stratification and geography impact on how the debate is perceived in Britain. The Brits remain wedded to a perplexing lexicon of meal-time terminology. The byzantine nature of all this provides us with even more food for thought by Somerset Maugham's dictum: "To eat well in England you should have breakfast three times a day.'

Answer (score 20):

My paternal grandfather grew up on a farm in the American Midwest in the 1920s and was fond of telling us about the day's schedule and the meals.

- Up before dawn to milk the cow, while food was prepared so that *"breakfast"* came around dawn and was typically a solid, hot meal.
- Then into the fields to work until *"lunch"* (a small meal usually sandwiches or cold leftovers) was delivered in the late morning (say 10:30 or 11:00).
- Back to work until mid afternoon (3:30 or 4:00 pm) when they'd return to the house for a small hot meal called *"dinner"*.
- Milk the cows, chop wood, carry water, fix things, and other work near the house until *"supper"*, a large hot meal was served sometime after dark.

I talked to others who lived on farms in that time, and they reported similar things. I never know anyone to hold that schedule *off* the farm, however.

---

Aside: you'll notice that the above represents the men's day, but that the women evidently had their hands just as full. In large measure with doing all that cooking. Sheesh!

Comment: An excellent schedule to emulate, without all that work in between.

Comment: The day schedule heavily depends on the culture and profession you look at. I grew up on a small farm in Austria. My parents - lifetime farmers - lived on a similar schedule.

Depending on workload or time of year you can reach five times to eat (breakfast before you start work; a small cold snack between breakfast and noon; the main meal at noon; sometimes a snack, often with coffee in the mid of afternoon; and finally something to eat after your days labour).

Also in German there are lots of names for all those meals. It strongly depends on your milieu.

Comment: I adopted this eating schedule in college. Sometimes I also supplemented it with a midnight Taco Bell or Walmart run...I have a really high metabolism.

Comment: Yes, let us not forget a "midnight feast". It's something of a misnomer since whatever was eaten very late at night or after midnight was never feast-like in quantity or quality.

Comment: Farmers in the 1950s north of Lisbon followed a pattern similar to that described by @DohnJoe : breakfast (called the 'bug-killer') before leaving to the fieds, hot meals on the field (usually delivered by a kid) later in the morning and early in the afternoon, cold snack later, and another hot meal in the evening. Wine they would have all day round. But by the 1970s the mid-morning hot meal had been replaced by a snack or eliminated altogether, and the early afternoon hot meal moved to noon.

Answer (score 15):

In India, *supper* is rarely (if ever) used.

- *Lunch* – refers to the afternoon meal (somewhere between noon to 2 pm)
- *Tea* – refers to tea and snacks around evening time (4pm - 6pm)
- *Dinner* – refers to a meal at night (after evening, 7pm to 10 pm).

The size of the meal has little relation to the name. Though I'm sure that both Lunch and Dinner are fairly heavy. Tea is definitely only light snacks (a clear relic of the British rule).

Brunch is also increasingly used for a lazy combination of Breakfast and Lunch !

Comment: Yes, and there's also 'tiffin', a snack or light meal at midday (Oxford Dictionary) which was a word in common usage by the colonial Brits and their cohorts during the days of the British Raj in India, 19th & early-mid 20th centuries. It was brought back to Britain by the returning ruling elite but never really a found a place for itself in the mother country or its vernacular.

Answer (score 13):

Where I live (SE-US), *supper* is more likely to connotate a quiet family meal, whereas *dinner* is just like lunch only later.  *Supper* seems to be preferred in more rural areas.

However, 30–40 years ago it was different.  People in my region called the meals "breakfast", "dinner", and "supper", in that order.  Later the Northerners brought their style of saying "breakfast", "lunch", "dinner", in that order.  This seems to me to explain why *supper* has survived in some rural areas, as those people would be in contact with the fewest number of people that speak differently.

Answer (score 10):

On the farm in Arkansas in the 1930's we had dinner at noon, which was our big meal which would be chicken and dumplings or fried chicken or pork or maybe rabbit, squirrel and sometimes beef if we didn't sell it.  For supper in the evening after we came in from the field about dark we would eat mostly beans and cornbread.

Comment: What did you have for breakfast?

Answer (score 8):

Born in Southwestern Ontario, Canada, raised in a traditional British household.

*Breakfast* – Morning meal breaking the overnight fast.

*Morning Tea* – tea and biscuit, sometimes a replacement for Afternoon Tea for those who dislike caffeine so close to bed time.

*Lunch* – Midday meal.

*Afternoon Tea* – 4 o'clock tea and biscuit.

*Dinner* – Largest, most formal end-of-day meal. Taken at a Dinner table with full cutlery and dishware.

*Supper* – Small informal meal taken before bed usually in a kitchen type setting.

Answer (score 6):

I'm from Africa, Nigeria, of Ibo extraction. During our primary school days, we were taught that *breakfast* is the morning meal, *lunch* afternoon, *supper* evening and *dinner* night.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a California native with parents who moved here from Maryland/Kansas and Indiana. Both sides of my family used *dinner* and *supper* interchangeably when referring to everyday meals. However, they used *Sunday dinner* when referring to a meal served on Sunday, generally between 2:00 and 3:00, as was also our custom for Thanksgiving, Christmas, and Easter, with leftovers being eaten for our evening meal. As I read these posts, I couldn't help wonder why the immortal painting was named *The Last Supper*. I wonder what time of day that meal took place?

Comment: Leonardo da Vinci's painting ('The Last Supper') of Jesus and his apostles (New Testament, Gospel of John 13:21) depicts a Passover or Pesach Seder celebrated by the Jewish people to commemorate the exodus of the Israelites from enslavement in Egypt (Old Testament, Book of Exodus). The "supper" would have commenced at sunset and featured unleavened bread (matzo) and a number of symbolic food items and wine used and eaten at this annual religious gathering.

Answer (score 5):

Well – I got into this because I have come across references on Prince Edward Island, Canada, to lunch as an evening meal.  When I checked the original meaning of the word "luncheon" it seems the original Oxford defined it as a small meal between two larger meal.  Specifically, in L.M. Montgomery's *Emily of New Moon,* Emily's family spend the day travelling.  When they arrive home in the evening they are so tired that they eat a light lunch before retiring to bed (apologies for not being able to provide a direct quote at this moment).  Recently I also heard my neighbour on PEI refer to "lunch" as an light evening meal.

I have noted in Canada, the use of "turkey dinner", "lobster supper" and special meal patterns not familiar to me in Australia.

Growing up in Australia, it was breakfast in the early morning, morning tea mid morning, dinner at midday (hot main meal), afternoon tea mid-afternoon, tea in the early evening (sandwiches, soup etc) and then supper before bed (cup of tea/cocoa, piece of cake).  As time went on, work further away from home no longer permitted the midday "dinner".  The main meal moved to early evening (6 to 8pm) but I often refer to this main cooked evening meal as "tea" which really annoys my English-born husband.  My family originally came from the north of England (well, Cheshire anyway), and I noted elsewhere someone had this usage of "tea" for the North of England.

Answer (score 5):

This thread shows the dangers of the English language and reminds me of *Through the Looking Glass*: "'When I use a word,' Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, 'it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less.' "

Being a middle-class middle-aged southern Englishman it is quite clear what I mean:  *Lunch* is the midday meal, *tea* is taken around 4/5pm and *supper* is the evening meal. If the evening meal is more formal and substantial it becomes *dinner.*  Lower down the social scale the midday meal is *dinner,* *tea* is the evening meal and *supper* is a snack at bed time.

25 years ago my sister's son was newly enrolled at a State primary school in a relatively poor area.  After a few weeks she had to call in at the administrative office.  She was greeted with "Mrs Sherry, so pleased to meet you, I have been dying to meet the only parent who writes 'lunch money' on the envelope containing dinner money."

In England you need to know about someone's education, age, and class, region and politics to be reasonably sure of understanding exactly what he means :)

Answer (score 3):

Not to disagree with any of the previous answers, but I am surprised that no one has mentioned that "dinner" can have two meanings. Only that of a mealtime has been addressed. *Dinner* can also mean the meal itself. They seem identical but consider the following sentences: "We enjoyed an elaborate turkey dinner"; "we had turkey for dinner". This distinction seems to mirror a lot of the conventions that other posters have made. With this in mind, would it be incorrect to say that one enjoyed a turkey dinner for supper? I don't know—it sure sounds weird.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Personally, I think the other answers equate the type/size of meal with what time of day it is eaten and I think the two are intertwined. No, I don't think you can properly say *one enjoyed a turkey dinner for supper*. You could say *one enjoyed a turkey **meal** for supper*, but, as the other answers say, the use of 'dinner' is indicating that it's the main meal of the day, and 'supper' is indicating a lighter meal. You can't properly mix them.

Comment: @TrevorD: It's fine that you don't think they can be mixed; but you don't really explain anything. You just state that you agree with other answers. The whole point of Kyle's answer is to say that there is an *orthogonal* meaning which hadn't been brought up in other answers. You **absolutely** can say "I had a TV dinner for supper", for example, and it's perfectly proper.

Comment: People do in fact mix them, whether that's "proper" or not. Even to the extent that you'll sometimes hear something like "we're having sandwiches for dinner, and dinner for tea", so that using "dinner" to describe the meal and the mealtime occurs in the same sentence. That would happen among people who mainly call the midday meal "dinner" and the evening meal "tea", but are also influenced by the "main meal is called dinner" usage. Both my parents moved south within England during childhoods, so my family's vocabulary is scattershot, but it's not just them I've heard this sort of thing from.

Answer (score 3):

The use of 'supper' in southern England is not universal.  Commonly, people appropriate this word for an evening meal to make themselves sound grand.

Growing up, we would have breakfast, lunch and tea and then, as the [NZ chap](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/128291/77227) wrote, cocoa/hot chocolate and biscuits as supper at around 9pm.  This was in London.

Nowadays, my brother refers to his evening meal as 'dinner'; I still refer to it as 'tea'.  I baulk when I read about 'supper clubs'.  Seems a bit socially exclusive (to the upper middle classes) to me.

Comment: A "fish-supper", quite possibly bought in from a local chip shop (chippie) in the UK, is far from being an affectation to sound "grand" [sic].  However, I would accept that "supper" - the word and its concept - was not used by the working classes in UK. But equally it was often used by other social classes to indicate a lighter, more informal meal than dinner (nothing grandiose about that), even as a "late supper" between "two" at night with the contrived intention of seduction on the "menu".  Witness Laurence Olivier & Marilyn Monroe in the movie, The Prince and the Showgirl

Answer (score 2):

Before I moved to Canada from UK, I thought the mid-day meal was "lunch" and the evening meal "dinner." I didn't even know that working-class people in UK called "dinner" "supper." The latter I thought of as a pre-bedtime snack. That ghastly N. American hybrid, "brunch," was a completely unheard-of word. When we had "tea," it was usually just that (perhaps a cucumber sandwich or biscuit [never a "cookie"], too), but never "high tea," which was considered working-class by some people. Canadians use both "dinner" and "supper," I think. Getting rid of these stupid class distinctions would be a help etymologically as well as socially!

Answer (score 2):

I grew internationally since my parents travelled a lot. Literally, I was raised in European, American, Asian countries as well as remote islands; therefore depending on your lifestyle and culture:

- Breakfast = From 2:00am - 10:00am
- Coffee = From 4:00am - 10:00am (also a drink/beverage)
- Brunch = From  10:00am - 1:00pm (used mainly on weekends & social gatherings).
- Lunch = From 11:00am - 2:00pm
- Tea = From 2:00pm - 5:00pm (also a drink/beverage)
- Dinner = From 5:00pm - 10:00pm
- Supper = From 7:00pm - 12:00am
- Snack = (single food item between meals)

Meal terms also depending on what you had to eat & drink, as well as number of courses and who was coming or who you were speaking to social, economic & cultural setting.

Example: If mom had coffee, tea, cakes, cookies/biscuits "friends coming over at 10:00am be dressed"--she was having company over for Coffee. If it was at 3:00pm it was company for Tea.

If she had pancakes, eggs, bacon, coffee, tea, fruit punch at 10:00am, we were having Breakfast.
If breakfast also had rice, potatoes, meats, sandwiches & friends—she was serving Brunch.
If there were no breakfast items and only the soups, sandwiches or rice, potatoes, meats, we were having Lunch.

If the Lunch menu items was being served at 5:00pm—we were having Dinner. If it was lighter fare at 8:00pm with friends—she was having Supper.

If she handed you cookies/biscuits and milk when you came home from school—that was just a Snack.

You pretty much had to look at the date and time, look at the menu, see who was coming (or where you were going), and how you were dressed (formal, semi-formal, informal, casual).

Whew ... hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

*Supper* is any meal had from 4 p.m. till late. And *dinner* can be seen as a special kind of supper that sometimes comes occasionally, a lot more food is served than at supper.

Answer (score 1):

I grew up in the midwest—small town, rural area in the 1950's.  The meal in the morning was always breakfast.  The meal in the evening was always supper.  The mid-day meal was either lunch (a light meal, maybe a sandwich and soup) or dinner (large, like Sunday Dinner or Thanksgiving dinner).

Answer (score 1):

I'm from New Zealand. In my experience, people in New Zealand generally use the following:

- *breakfast* = morning meal
- *lunch* = meal around noon
- *tea* (or dinner, less common) = evening meal
- *supper* = late evening snack

also:

- *morning tea* = drinks and snacks mid-morning
- *afternoon tea* = drinks and snacks in the afternoon

Morning tea and afternoon tea are also called "smoko" – particularly in more physical jobs, such as farming or construction.

I don't think "supper" is very common, but when I stayed in a hall of residence at university in 1996, they served "supper" at around 9pm. It was usually something like some hot tea/cocoa and a muffin or piece of cake. "Supper" sounds a bit old fashioned or formal to me – if I have a snack in the evening now I wouldn't call it "supper" – just a "snack".

Answer (score 0):

*Breakfast* is a very early morning hot meal to start the day.

*Brunch* became known as a combination late breakfast/early lunch.

*Lunch* was solely the noonday meal.

*Tea time* is the same as coffee time served with cake or cookies in the late afternoon.

*Supper* is the main meal for a family at end of the day.

*Dinner* is a more formal term for the end of the day meal which usually includes the accompanying of friends, a date, business partners, or persons other than just family and usually included cocktails prior to the meal.

*Cigars and Brandy* is a time mostly for men after a dinner and is surely a southern term not used much at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When I was a child in rural Southside Virginia (in the early 1940s), "dinner" was the main meal* of the day – usually midday during the week or mid-afternoon on Sunday.

* "Breakfast" might have been "larger" nutritional calorie-wise but "dinner" was more elaborate and varied from time to time.

In my travels (around this country and much of the world) and in my old age, I have come to agree with the "Humpty Dumpty" reference above.

Answer (score 0):

From Maryland:  I've always understood DINNER as a large (in size and attendence), with a "main dish" (usually meat) with many accompanying sides, and possibly  a formal gathering, main evening meal; and SUPPER as a small, intimate among family "single pot" meal like soup, casserole, or pot pie.  Sometimes supper would come after an early dinner (like on holidays) and would be made from dinner leftovers.  Most days went breakfast–lunch–dinner, on weekends breakfast–dinner–supper, or breakfast–lunch–dinner–supper, or busy days out of the house might be breakfast–lunch–late supper.

Answer (score 0):

To add some more to the subject, in 1900 the Republican Party(US) ran the campaign slogan ["Four years more and the full dinner pail.'](https://www.encyclopedia.com/history/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/full-dinner-pail)

[image]

Clearly a successful national party would not be referring to what we now call a "lunch box" as a "dinner pail" if there was no general understanding of what "dinner" meant.
This suggests to me that "lunch" had not yet arrived as the usual term for midday meal in the US. And, the campaign could not have been aimed at the agrarian South, as the Republican Party had little traction there; the South was still solidly Democratic. Also, this could not be a slogan to attract Western farmers, as farmers usually did not take their meals with them into the fields. The "dinner bell" must have been ringing for a lot of people outside agriculture at the time.

Comment: This would work better as a comment

Comment: @Mitch......maybe, but to be any use, it needed some space. I suppose I think a down-voted answer better than an ignored comment.

Comment: I think comments should be higher status objects here and this is a good example of it.

Comment: @Mitch... I understand.  There is a certain cavalier attitude about propriety, an inconsistency. Fortunately, there is nothing life or death involved.