# How are 24-hour (military) times read aloud?

Tags: time, speech

I understand you read 2000 aloud as *twenty hundred hours* and 0000 as *zero hours*.

How then do you read 0001 and 0010?

Comment: i think 1 second? and a 10 minute? would be better?

Comment: @JavaD Where does seconds come into it?

Comment: *If* I were reading it *strictly* in 24 hour format, I would read "0000" as "zero *hundred* hours" - not just "zero hours" as in the question. (But see my answer below.)

Comment: What about "zero hundred one" and "zero hundred ten"?

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/122325/44619

Answer (score 5):

- 0001: zero zero zero one (hours)
- 0010: zero zero ten (hours)

Sometimes, instead of zero, *oh* is used, although this is a more colloquial form.
From what I have read, whether or not the "hours" part is pronounced depends on the branch of military; usually it is understood to be implicit and thus left out.

http://www.wikihow.com/Tell-Military-Time

Comment: Do you mean you say "zero zero zero one hours in the plural form" or "zero zero zero one hour in the singular form?"

Comment: Added some clarification.

Comment: Why the assumption that this question has anything to do with the military?

Answer (score 4):

<sub>This is an expanded and edited version of my original answer, with additional material included primarily to address various comments below my original answer suggesting that:</sub>

- <sub>"I take the asker's writing of both the numerical values and their pronunciations to be indications that he is indeed asking about how the times are said in a military context, rather than in generic English contexts around the world."

  [Response: OP's question does not mention "military" at all; the numeric format and terminology is not restricted to the military as explained below. OP has not commented on this point.]</sub>
- <sub>"the 24-hour system ... is not the same as the military system"

  [Response: The *formal* military system is one format of the 24-hour system, and differences/similarities between it and civilian usage vary. "The **24-hour clock** ... is popularly referred to as **military time** in [various] countries." See quotations and discussion below.]</sub>
- <sub>"hours and minutes (and seconds) are ... always separated by something in the 24-hour system, while they are never separated in the military system"

  [Response: Both separated and unseparated formats are permitted by ISO 8601 and are in common usage, as shown below.]</sub>

---

#### Definitions

> The **24-hour clock** is the convention of time keeping in which the day runs from midnight to midnight and is divided into 24 hours, indicated by the hours passed since midnight, from 0 to 23. This system is the most commonly used time notation in the world today, and is the international standard (ISO 8601) notation for time of day. ... It is popularly referred to as **military time** or **astronomical time** in the United States, Canada, and a handful of other countries where the **12-hour clock** is still dominant.
>   [Wikipedia 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock)
>
> **ISO 8601** uses the 24-hour clock system. The basic format is [hh][mm][ss] and the extended format is [hh]:[mm]:[ss].
>
> - [hh] refers to a zero-padded hour between 00 and 24 (where 24 is only used to notate midnight at the end of a calendar day).
> - [mm] refers to a zero-padded minute between 00 and 59.
> - [ss] refers to a zero-padded second between 00 and 60 (where 60 is only used to notate an added leap second).
>
> So a time might appear as either "134730" in the basic format or "13:47:30" in the extended format.
>   It is also acceptable to omit lower order time elements for reduced accuracy: [hh]:[mm], [hh][mm] and [hh] are all used.
>   [Wikipedia 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times)

#### Military time

Although the 24-hour system of writing time is often "popularly referred to as "military time in the United States, Canada, and a handful of other countries where the **12-hour clock** is still dominant" [4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock), in much of the rest of the world it is now the normal format for writing times unambiguously without using "a.m." and "p.m.", especially in schedules, timetables, and many other documents. (In fact, personally, I now get confused when looking at websites that do *not* display the time in 24-hour format.)

The previous answer gives a link to a website for "Tell-Military-Time", and also refers to possible differences between different of the military. It would appear that that site actually describes usage *within the US Military*.  Personally, I would be hesitant is assuming that any usage described there corresponds to common usage within other English-speaking countries worldwide.  That would be especially so, because *within the military*, they are speaking with others trained in using the same terminology, whereas in the 'outside world' you may be speaking to someone not familiar with particular terminology.

#### Numeric format

As indicated in the extract quoted previously, the ISO standard permits the presence or absence of separators between the digits representing the hours, minutes and seconds. But it does specify that, when a separator is used, it should be a colon.

> In the past, some European countries used the dot on the line as a separator, but most national standards on time notation have since then been changed to the international standard colon. In some contexts (e.g., U.S. military, some computer protocols), no separator is used (e.g., 2359). [5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Description)

See the following examples:

Some airlines use a colon separator [[Image source](http://www.virgin-atlantic.com/gb/en/travel-information/flight-status.html?t=d&date=2013-08-18&js_depflight=London%2C+Gatwick+Airport%2C+UK%2C+GB+%28LGW%29&flightStatusSelect=LGW&checkFlightStatus=checkFlightStatus)]:
[image: Virgin Atlanic timetable extract]

Several UK railway timetables use no separator symbol, but use a small space [[Image source](http://www.southernrailway.com/download/26699.4/15-crawley-and-horsham/)]:
[image: Southern Railway timetable extract]

Several UK bus companies use no separator at all [[Image source](http://www.compass-travel.co.uk/timetables/service_16.html)]:
[image: Compass Bus timetable extract]

<sub>[I have found many other examples of each format, but will not illustrate or list them here.]</sub>

#### Speaking the time

Reverting now to OP's basic question of how to express 24-hour time in speech, military protocols may specify exact formulae, but in civilian usage:

*Personally*, I would **not** refer to:

- 0001 as *zero zero zero one hours*
- 0010 as *zero zero ten hours*

for fear that it may be misunderstood as "one hour" or "ten hours" after midnight. I would probably say:

> one minute past midnight
>   ten minutes past midnight

but, depending who I was talking to, I might use any of the following:

> midnight oh one
>   zero hours one minute
>   twelve oh one †
>   one minute past twelve †

† if it were already clear that we were referring to *midnight* and not *noon*.
Or any other similar expression that came to mind.

In summary, my answer to the questioner would be that (outside the military and other officialdom) there is no formal set way of expressing times in the 24-hour clock, and I would suggest expressing it in any suitable *unambiguous* manner that would be understood by the person to whom you are talking, even if that means 'translating' the time into a traditional or 12-hour format.

Comment: I have never seen the format used in the question used in anywhere other than military and programming. I use the 24-hour system, but that is _not_ the same as the military system—for one thing, hours and minutes (and seconds) are in my experience always separated by something in the 24-hour system, while they are never separated in the military system. Also, times are read differently: 21:00 would never be read as ‘twenty-one hundred hours’, but simply as ‘nine o’clock’ (or similar).

Comment: To be more clear, I take the asker's writing of both the numerical values and their pronunciations to be indications that he is indeed asking about how the times are said _in a military context_, rather than in generic English contexts around the world.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet His question refers specifically to the "24-hour time system". He does *not* refer to the "military system" **at all**, which is mentioned **only** in the other answer. OP's name appears to be Japanese, but with no indication where he is from. Maybe he is in Japan and learning English and has seen that format. Who knows?! One answerer apparently made one assumption based on the format in the question. I made a different assumption based on the question's title. I disagree that 21:00 would never be read as ‘twenty-one hundred hours’. What is your basis for that statement?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet To be more clear, you may make whatever assumption you like from the question. I may make a different assumption. That is no reason for making your disagreement so vehement. The question is ambiguous in a way that I had not realised: I would have no objection to you having pointed that out in a 'neutral' manner, but I take strong objection to the tone of your comments. And **if** the downvote was yours, then at least have the courage to indicate so, as is recommended in the site FAQs.

Comment: Any vehemence or tone perceived in my comment lies entirely in your interpretation; the comment was meant to be entirely neutral. The basis for my statement that ‘21:00’ would never be read as ‘twenty-one hundred hours’ is, as for the orthographic separation of hours and minutes, that I have never heard it. “24-hour time system” is ambiguous to me (being any system that is based on a day having 24 unique hours, rather than 12 repeated hours, military or not), but the notation “2100” and the mentioning of hundreds is not. The downvote was not mine; it was subsequent to my comment.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet (1) Starting a second comment with "To be more clear" & then re-emphasising what your first comment already said seems pretty vehement to me! (2) You state that "The basis for [your] statement that ‘21:00’ would never be read as ‘twenty-one hundred hours’ is ... that [you] have never heard it." That is hardly *independent* collaboration, especially when *I* state that *I have heard it* (and have used it)! (3) This is an *English Language* website - not a military website - and I read and answered the question accordingly.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet (4) Your last comment said "'24-hour time system' is ambiguous". OP's title had "*the* 24-hour system" & your first comment stated "*the* 24-hour system ... is not the same as the military system" (& later used the same term to refer to the *non-military* system). So please do not now allege that the title is ambiguous, when you have previously *exactly used the same term* as a distinction. I do accept that the title & content of the question *taken together* may be ambiguous, which I had not previously appreciated. Without OP's input we will not know which was intended.

Comment: The “to be more clear” part was intended to be a clarification of what I thought was perhaps vague in my first comment, namely the reason for writing it in the first place. I do not know of a specific term for the non-military 24-hour system, so yes, I ended up being ambiguous: when I said that I use ‘the 24-hour system’, I should have more specific and emphasised that I meant the _civilian_ 24-hour system (or whatever its proper name, if any, may be), as ‘24-hour system’ on its own could be both.

Comment: Just my tuppence worth. In Italian when we read 20.00 we **can say**: *le ore otto* ("eight hours" = eight o'clock/8 p.m.) or *le otto di sera* (eight in the evening) or *le (ore) venti* (twenty/twenty hours) so, despite being very flexible it's never ambiguous, unlike "8 o'clock" in the UK or the US.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have amplified my answer to address most of the points you raised. Specifically I have provided proof that the format *2100* with *no separators* **is** used in non-military contexts. I have provided one illustration, but found several more instances.