# Late Night vs Early Morning

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases

Can anyone explain me Difference between late night & early morning ?

"I slept early morning".Is this sentence correct ?

What time is called morning ? After 12:00 AM ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited to ELL.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Come on, Maybe opinion-based but the definition of night, day, morning, evening and afternoon, when taking into account latitude is much more 'serious English language enthusiasts' than ELL surely. Svalbard in winter, only twilight and night.

Comment: Probably this question isn't duplicate.http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28498/precise-names-for-parts-of-a-day doesnot defines late night & early morning.

Comment: There's a difference between this and the other cited question. Whoever quoted this question as duplicate is not an expert in English language & usage.

Comment: @Frank 'This is the only site that requires a mastery of basic English.' [RyeɃreḁd, meta] It is a 'site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.' Also, an in-house search for "Night Early Morning" gives the duplicated thread.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for pointing me to meta - interesting reading in some places.

Comment: @Frank If only everyone posting here read and tried to keep to the guidelines, there would be a tightening up of standards, which would be in almost everyone's interests. Apart from the selfish spammer, of course. Varying standards and entrenched subjective views are unhelpful to sincere enquirers.  I hope you observe the rule 'Bow ties must be worn at all times when submitting answers except for those addressing Australian usages'?

Comment: 'does not define _late night_ and _early morning_': I'd say agreed definitions aren't available, and this question can only be answered broadly, subjectively, and with regard to context. Barmar's 'There's no definite time when late night turns into early morning – it's generally a matter of perspective, although I think many would consider it [to be] somewhere between 3am and 5am.' is the most sensible attempt at an answer here, I think, and I would accept it (though 2:30 is my preferred transition point).

Answer (score 3):

There's no definite time when late night turns into early morning, it's generally a matter of perspective, although I think many would consider it somewhere between 3am and 5am. For instance, you might consider it night until you go to sleep, and it's morning when you wake up. Of course, if you stay up all night, it eventually becomes morning, but there's no fixed time -- perhaps it's when you decide that it's too late to go to sleep, so you decide to stay up.

*I slept early morning* is not correct. You could say *I woke up early in the morning* or *I didn't get to sleep until late at night.*

Answer (score 1):

*Morning*. I would say *sunrise until noon*, but in northern latitudes where sunrise can be late in the winter and early in the summer it's probably averaged out to about 06:00.

*Night*. I would say *sunset to sunrise*, again in northern latitudes, probably, averaged out to about 18:00 until 06:00.

An early morning would be waking up before 06:00, a late night would be going home after 06:00. (*a late night* usually means you have been out with your friends enjoying yourself - rather than simply going to bed later than is normal)

It's easier when you live on the Equator, 12 hours of light, 12 hours of dark.

Comment: `a late night would be going home after 06:00`...So What you call as night ? :)

Comment: Night would be between 18:00 and 06:00, a late night is after night has finished (although my wife would think a late night was any time after 02:00 !)

Comment: I am satisfied with your definition of late night and early morning. But i like Calypto definition of morning & night.What should i do ? I can accept only one answer.

Comment: @MADTerry Upvote the ones you like and then accept Calypto

Comment: Kind hearted @frank :)

Answer (score 0):

Morning is when the sun has risen. It would be after 5 am, since that's the time period the sun generally rises at.

12:00 am is essentially midnight.

After midnight, a time phase called zenith occurs.

And then, dawn follows, wherein you can't see the sun yet but perceive its weak rays in the horizon.

> The other question:
>
> The thing is "I slept early morning" is not a good practice as is saying "Good Night" when it's already morning. The correct sentence is "I didn't get to sleep until early in the morning."

Comment: Liked your answer. But answers only one question.

Comment: To answer your other question, well, you can definitely sleep early in the morning and I would say "Good Night" to you and go for a morning walk. (pun intended)

Comment: The thing is "I slept early morning" is not a good practice as is saying good night when it's already morning. The correct sentence is - "I didn't get to sleep until early in the morning."

Comment: I am satisfied with Frank definition of late night and early morning. But i like Calypto definition of morning & night.What should i do ? I can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is nearly impossible to give timings to the minute about such understandings, I will be assuming the inclusive reckoning of time theory in my answer. That is, 5:59 am is still counted as 5am. If not, I would have so many plus signs in my post! :P

On equator, this is our common definition:

Dawn: Sun has not risen but some rays can be perceived. However, the sky is still dark blue, around 3am to 5am.

**Early morning: Sun has risen and it's rays permit the skies to have a hue of orange around 6am to 8am**

**Morning: Sun has completely risen and the skies are bright, around 9am to 10am**

**Late morning: 11am**

**Some people count 11am as early afternoon (Like KFC and McDonald's 11am is lunchtime for them)**

Afternoon: Sun is at it's peak and it is the hottest time of the day 12pm to 2pm
*Late afternoon: Sun begins to descend and it is not as bright or hot as at 12pm, around 3pm to 4pm

Evening: Sun starts to set and the skies spark a little orange, around 5pm to 6:30pm

**Night: Sun sets and skies darken, no orange and going on dark blue, around 7pm to 9pm**

**Late night: Pitch black, around 10pm to 11pm**

Midnight: 12am

When it is after 12 am, it cannot be late night anymore since a new **day** has already started.

**Late night = The previous day**

**Early morning = The present day**

So, did you sleep the previous day or did you only get to sleep today? Big difference.

Night is actually not perceived by the colour of the sky but rather, it is the separation between yesterday and today.

Comment: You haven't defined morning. I didn't ask definitions of all phases of day.

Comment: In early morning, morning and late morning, I wrote that the sun has risen, the difference being the time and the difference being the words early and late. So, in any case, early or late details the time of the day or, specifically, how far are we into the morning/night. However, if you need me to be so specific, I will edit and separate morning and late morning.

Comment: Edits are done. No you didn't ask for the definitions. However, if I had given you early morning to late morning is 6am to 11am, then you might have asked me so what time is morning or early morning or you might have asked me is 11am considered afternoon? It would be never-ending so I just gave you all.