# Can supper and dinner be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Lunch” vs. “dinner” vs. “supper” — times and meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22446/lunch-vs-dinner-vs-supper-times-and-meanings)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supper) states that the words *supper* and dinner can be used interchangeably. But I am not thoroughly convinced as, well, they are two different words.

According to Merriam-Webster dictionary:

[**Supper**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supper) is *a light meal served late in the evening*.

[**Dinner**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dinner) is *the principal meal of the day*.

I am confused as to if at all using these words interchangeably would be deemed correct and if so, under what circumstances?

***NOTE:*** The question [Lunch vs. dinner vs. supper — times and meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22446/lunch-vs-dinner-vs-supper-times-and-meanings) attracted some attention but the last sentence in the accepted answer put me off!

> So whether you use Lunch/Dinner or Dinner/Supper is heavily determined by when your culture traditionally has its largest meal.

Maybe, I eat breakfast like a king, lunch like a prince, and dinner like a pauper. That doesn't make my breakfast my dinner right? ;)

Comment: This isn't just an issue with English—the three main meals are _petit déjeuner_, _déjeuner_, and _dîner_ in France, but _déjeuner_, _dîner, and _souper_ in the Francophone parts of Canada, Belgium, and Switzerland.

Comment: First of all, is this supposed to be a question in its own right or really just a comment on an accepted answer elsewhere? Second, how on Earth do you get from "whether you use *lunch/dinner* or *dinner/supper* is heavily determined by when your culture traditionally has its largest meal" to "if I breakfast like a king, that makes my breakfast my dinner"? Complete and utter non sequitur. What's more, the sentence that put you off actually *answers* your question here. (If some people use the dinner/supper combo, certainly at least for these people the two are not interchangeable.)

Comment: @RegDwighт: Take it down a notch pal. I don't understand what you fuming over? If you are read whats written above the Note, there is a genuine question. And the Note was added to keep two very close but different questions apart. The "_utter non sequitur_" you are talking about is just a joke. I thought the emoticon would make that amply clear.

Comment: I think that other question ably demonstrates the the answer is either "Yes", "No" or "Depends", and I reckon this is a duplicate.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher if that was too much fuming for your tastes, here's a simpler wording. I consider this question rhetorical because you have answered it yourself.

Comment: @RegDwighт: Have I really? I see that in the edit to your comment(_in which, to my relief you are not appalled anymore_)  you have mentioned that `If some people use the dinner/supper combo, certainly at least for these people the two are not interchangeable.` But its not a question if it might be okay for **some** people, but if it is **correct** to use them interchangeably? And if yes, under what circumstances?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I had not figured that the answer would be either "_Yes_", "_No_" or "_Depends_"! Care to back any of those with some substance(reference) in an answer? And the allegedly duplicate question you are talking bout is explicitly mentioned in the question, to explain why that post didn't help me answer this question. I sincerely urge you to read the question **completely**.

Comment: @KeyBrd Basher: You seem to be fixated on the idea that there should be a single "correct" answer here. But there simply isn't - check out [Callithumpian's painstaking answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/22824/2637) and ask yourself what it would mean to say that tens of millions of English-speaking people are somehow using everyday words like *dinner* "incorrectly". To a first approximation, a word means what people intend it to mean, *which varies across subcultures*. Correctitude is for the birds, so I'm closevoting this as a duplicate.

Comment: I have no idea what puts you off about the final sentence of the accepted answer. On some days I have lunch then supper. On others I have lunch then dinner. On still others — like Christmas — I have dinner then supper. All are right for their own days, and all mean — and therefore tell you — several different important things.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: `a word means what people intend it to mean, which varies across subcultures.` Maybe this is what I was missing out on, coz in our culture we never have dinner during the day.

Comment: @tchrist: My point being exactly that! You do have supper and dinner at different times of the day, right? So they are not one and the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crux of your question appears to be: can the words *supper and dinner* be used interchangeably?

According to established dictionary definitions, the answer would seem to be yes. From Oxford English Dictionary (OED) –

> supper, n.1
>
> 1. The last meal of the day; (contextually) the time at which this is eaten, supper time.

And also from OED –

> dinner, n.
>
> The chief meal of the day, eaten originally, and still by the majority of people, about the middle of the day (cf. German Mittagsessen), but now, by the professional and fashionable classes, usually in the evening;

So, according to those definitions, if you’ve eaten your main meal of the day, which also happens to be your last meal of the day, then *supper* and *dinner* can be used interchangeably to describe that meal.

Answer (score 0):

This is one question we used to ask our teachers frequently and they wouldn't know how to explain.

We all know that *dinner* always means the main meal of the day but it gets complicated when one considers both the mid-day meal and the meal one has before going to bed as *main* meals which is the case in India. But we can't call both meals *dinner*. So the common custom here is to have *lunch* in the afternoon and *dinner* before going to bed and consider the the difference between the two settled.

We just don't use the word *supper*.