# When is afternoon? When is evening? When is night? Is there another meal after dinner?

Tags: meaning, time, food, cultural-correctness

I'm a beginner here, and I have a question about the evening/night meal, and this is my first question.

> It's evening. The family is eating dinner.

1. From when until when is it considered to be "evening" in English? And from when until when is it considered "night"? Are these completely distinct or are they overlapping concepts?
2. I’m an Iranian. In Iran, we consider "evening" to run all the way from afternoon until sunset (4 pm – 8 pm), while "night" ***for us*** runs from right after sunset until the next sunrise; and we eat "dinner" at night, normally around 10 o’clock at night.

So, does one eat another meal after "dinner"? It seems to me that "dinner" is an evening meal and people eat it very soon, so it should be not the meal that people eat late at night, as we do in Iran.

Comment: Those who eat their dinner earlier, say at 6-8pm might eat a light [supper](https://www.lexico.com/definition/supper) later on. Colloquially, some in the UK refer to their mid-day meal as "dinner" and the evening meal as "supper".

Comment: Most people in America do not eat another meal after dinner regardless of whether they eat dinner at 5:00pm or 6:30pm or 8pm.  If they get hungry again before bed they might have a snack before bed. And some people might get up out of bed to have a late-night snack.   But there’s typically only one “meal” after lunch.

Comment: Those who have a midday 'dinner' in the UK will probably have a later and perhaps more substantial 'tea' than others, and possibly a late supper.

Comment: @Jim the "supper" I mentioned after the dinner is more likely a snack, not a formal meal.

Comment: [Confused by the {/many} British having dinner around noon and tea in the early evening](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125090/confused-by-the-british-having-dinner-in-the-afternoon-and-tea-in-the-eveni) may also help.

Comment: There is also the late afternoon meal called "tea" which is a light meal, or "high tea" which is more substantial, but few will eat breakfast, lunch, tea, dinner *and* supper :)

Comment: In some rural areas of the US, "dinner" was traditionally eaten at midday, as a break from the labors of farming.

Comment: Thank you Mr./Ms. @WeatherVane. So, can one say that people eat dinner around 8 pm and then eat supper some hours later, maybe around 10:30 pm?

Comment: Thank you Mr. @EdwinAshworth. I read it, and it somewhat helped me, but based on the answers I guess there is not any specific rule about the times. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: There's a blend 'brunch' made up of 'breakfast' and 'lunch'. Brunch refers the meal between *breakfast* and *lunch*. For meal before *breakfast* and after *dinner*, you could say **brinner** — a blend of *breakfast* and *dinner* but don't expect all your listeners to understand what you mean by *brinner*. (I've just made it up).

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. @Jim. Your answer gives me a more clear view. So, I can say that people in Iran and the US eat the evening and night meals somehow the same.

Comment: Thanks again, Mr. @EdwinAshworth. I understood that people in the UK call the midday meal 'dinner', but what do they call 'lunch'?

Comment: Ah, well. I googled 'brinner' and it's already in use. [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/brinner) defines it differently.

Comment: @Qàtrè, Lunch is called lunch.

Comment: Oh, wow! Mr. @EdwinAshworth, I can say that 'tea' is somehow like our evening meals in Iran. We eat often a light snack, maybe with coffee or tea, around 5 pm, which is after our lunch (midday meal) and dinner (late night meal).

Comment: Oh, wow! Mr./Ms. @WeatherVane, I can say that 'tea' is somehow like our evening meals in Iran. We eat often a light snack, maybe with coffee or tea, around 5 pm, which is after our lunch (midday meal) and dinner (late night meal).

Comment: Thank you, Mr./Ms. @HotLicks, but what about lunch?

Comment: That's really interesting, Mr./Ms. @DecapitatedSoul! We don't have any meals similar to brinner in Iran. But, that would be very good for a person who goes to bed very late. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I'm sorry that I cannot like your answers because I don't have enough scores yet.

Comment: @Qàtrè - In that context "lunch" is a quick meal, while "dinner" is a longer more elaborate affair.

Comment: OK, now I understand its meaning. Thank you Mr./Ms. @HotLicks again.

Comment: It's difficult to cram it all in to one day : breakfast, elevenses, brunch, snack, lunch, afternoon tea, dinner, supper and nightcap.

Comment: @Nigel What on earth happened to [second breakfast? Are you trying to starve a poor hobbit to death?](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/blog/1786/hobbit-meals-to-celebrate-hobbit-day.html)

Comment: @NigelJ - You guys left out "lupper"!

Comment: _Some_ people in the UK call the midday meal 'dinner' and the evening meal 'tea'. Others call the midday meal 'lunch' and the evening meal 'dinner'. Check out the links you have been given to other questions about names of meals.

Comment: @NigelJ Yes :-))

Comment: @tchrist Of all the meals, I love the first and second breakfasts more than others :-))

Comment: Thank you Ms. @KateBunting. Yes, now I know what are they and what are their names.