# "Linder" or "linnder" for lunch/dinner

Tags: orthography

> We have plans for a late lunch / early dinner planned for 4:00 pm in
>   mid December.

I would like to indicate that it's more than lunch and less than dinner. I have heard it called *linder* or *linnder*. Advice is sought on spelling.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an effectively non-existent portmanteau. ***Brunch***, yes. ***Linner/Linder***, no.

Comment: Anyway, why wouldn't it be lun-der? :-)

Comment: This is appalling.

Comment: I don't believe there a term for a meal which combines the midday and evening meals, as *brunch* combines the morning and midday. I would simply say it is a late lunch if before 3, an early dinner after 3 (substitute *supper* as needed in your area or dialect). A light meal consumed in addition to lunch or dinner could be an *afternoon tea* (or simply *tea*).

Comment: For the record, "linner" is out there. It is not in common or widespread use, but I, for one, have heard it used informally (cf http://nypost.com/2010/06/13/the-ladies-who-linner/). I am not at all suggesting it should be bandied about, but have others at least *heard* this term before? In my own experience, it would be understood by some (at least in context), contrary to RyeBread's assertion about "linder".

Comment: it should be lunner.  There is no DER in either word.

Comment: In Britain we would call it tea! But I am prepared to call it by your name if I can linger longer at linder with lovely Linda!

Comment: @WS2 Some people, especially in northern England, use "tea" to mean the main evening meal. For extra confusion, such people often use "dinner" to mean "lunch" (especially as in "school dinner", "dinner lady" etc.).

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/linder#:~:text=ˈlində(r),a%20woolen%20undershirt%20or%20vest Linder. A woollen vest....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question appears to be off-topic because it is about an effectively non-existent portmanteau.

Comment: It might be understood in context if you've just talked about brunch and maybe other portmanteaus, but that doesn't mean it's generally comprehensible absent such context.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise against Linder, which nobody will understand.  Go with afternoon snack, early dinner, or happy hour.

Comment: I'm not convinced by "happy hour". At least in the UK, that would be a time at which a pub/bar sells alcohol at a reduced price and I don't think anyone would associate it with eating.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - it would probably be only used for business occasions.  I get emails from groups and people all the time saying, "Let's go out for happy hour."  This usually start around 4 or 5 but could start as early as 3 and late as 6.  You are right in it's usage though.

Answer (score 3):

For a later-than-lunch meal that is not expected to be as hearty as dinner, I would go with:

### supper

See also ["Lunch" vs. "dinner" vs. "supper" — times and meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22446/lunch-vs-dinner-vs-supper-times-and-meanings)

Comment: This is highly regional.  In my area that would mean we are eating at around 8-9 PM.

Comment: @RyeBread, the accepted answer to the linked question acknowledges that it's a regional distinction.

Answer (score 2):

The two portmanteaus (portmanteaux?):  **Linner** (Very late large lunch bordering on dinner) and **Brinner** (Breakfast food for dinner) are terms I have heard used on American television.

I would **NOT** go so far as to say they are wide-spread.  I think people will understand your meaning, but it will depend upon context.

*Linder* on the other hand is an unmitigated disaster of a portmanteau.   I have coined a term for words like this, a *portminotaur.*  That's when you attempt to make a portmanteau but wind up with a monster instead!

Comment: "Brunch" is well defined but would "linner" be a lunch-like dinner or a dinner-like lunch?

Comment: @DavidRicherby in what world is brunch well defined. I've seen brunch with a meat carving station, and I've seen nothing more than French toast and waffles, perhaps an omelette bar.  As to which would it be, my answer is … *yes*.

Comment: Meat being carved sounds a lot like a place that's trying to cater for people who might want lunch instead of brunch.

Comment: @David M.I hope you don't mind, but I will be unabashedly stealing the "portminotaur" word and its explanation :)

Comment: @JATerroba Not at all!  It is freely licensed for all to use.

Answer (score 2):

I think these uses only arose because of Seinfeld:

- http://www.seinology.com/scripts/script-134.shtml
- http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/356277#2791924

Separate point -- what do you actually mean by "more than lunch, less than dinner?" Amount of food? Heaviness of food? That is the message that you should focus on in choosing your replacement term.

Answer (score 1):

How about *dunch*? That would be dinner and lunch and could be eaten when you've missed lunch and need to catch up on meals. So you might miss dinner. It's not in chronological order but might sound more familiar to the ear than 'linder' or 'linner.'

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dunch):

> Blend of dinner +‎ lunch, probably in imitation of brunch.
>
> (informal, rare) A leisurely meal between lunch and dinner in the late afternoon or early evening (about 3-5 p.m.), usually instead of lunch or dinner.
>
> *I have a lunchtime meeting tomorrow, so let's have dunch together instead.*
> Synonyms: linner, lupper

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is that a word you have encountered regularly, or one of your own invention?

Comment: It's in Urban Dictionary. I was looking for a word to describe just that since I've had a flurry of busyness recently and need to use it frequently.