# "Having breakfast", "breakfasting", or "breaking fast"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, ing

The first is the most common (in the US, anyway). The last seems most correct, but also least-used, and may even be considered "archaic" by some. The second is ugly, but if "breakfast" is a noun, and *any* noun can be made a verb, then it is also correct.

What should I use?

Comment: What do you wish to convey, and to what audience?

Comment: they are all correct. And as you said "Breaking Fast" is archaic, it is where the word breakfast comes from.

Comment: Note too that *dining* would be the verb for *having dinner*, and yet we still tend to say *having dinner* or *eating dinner*.  (Not to mention that *dinner* can apply to either the lunch or supper meal, depending on the region.  And don't get me started on the verb "sup".  :) )

Comment: I wish to convey, primarily, what it is I'm doing. Secondarily, I wish to convey my respect for the English language and a certain command of it.

Comment: Seriously now; without any additional context, "breaking fast" may be thoroughly misunderstood. "Breakfasting" I would get, but I don't think it's a real word. So, "having breakfast" would get my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have observed, the eating of the first meal of the day is nowadays mainly expressed in terms of consuming *breakfast* as a noun: to *have breakfast*, *eat breakfast*, or *get breakfast*, or more formally *take breakfast*, or more colorfully *devour*, *scarf*, etc.

You *can* use *breakfast* as a verb. The dictionaries still cite this sense, e.g. [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/breakfast):

> *verb* [no object]
> Eat breakfast.
>
> > ‘she breakfasted on fried bread and bacon’

I would caution, however, that this usage is somewhat dated for conversational English. A search on *breakfasted*, for example, against various [BYU Corpora](https://www.english-corpora.org/) turns up mainly examples from literature or long-form journalism, albeit some in columns written in the first person. While this is no proof of non-usage (those are the media the corpora mainly index, plus it's hard to prove a negative), I would certainly say that among Americans, using *breakfast* as a verb in conversation sounds pompous. It is the kind of affectation you'd read in a resort brochure, or expect from a pre-war butler in a film. I would say the same is true of *lunch* and *sup* as verbs as well— though nothing is worse for that than seasons (e.g. *We summer in Banff and winter in Tamarindo*).

*Dine* and *dining*, in contrast, have taken on additional meanings and connotations, and are not necessarily tied to [whichever meal](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22446) is called *dinner* in a particular region. There is little [pearl-clutching](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pearl-clutching) over taking brunch in the dining room, or referring to a high-end, full-service restaurant whose signature dishes are lunch foods as *fine dining*.

---

To *break fast* is now primarily used to refer to the breaking of a religious fast. Indeed, the Wikipedia article at [break fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_fast) covers Jewish practice (the Muslim counterpart at [Iftar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iftar), Arabic for "break fast"). You can find references to *breaking fast* referring to the daily meal of breakfast—

> It was Europe's introduction to chocolate, Anderson argues, that helped to change people's perspective on the moral propriety of breaking fast in the morning hours. (Garber, Megan. "[The Most Contentious Meal of the Day](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2016/06/breakfast-the-most-contentious-meal-of-the-day/487220/)", *The Atlantic*, June 6, 2016)

— but they are again exclusively literary, not quoted conversation. While an educated person would understand the meaning if you invited him or her to *break fast* with you, s/he would probably find it unusual, and if you told the average customer in a breakfast restaurant you were eager to *break fast*, they'd probably think you were making a bad joke.

Comment: Oh, so "to breakfast" is a real verb? I never heard of it. OK then.