# Does "Banquet" refer only to dinner?

Tags: meaning

Longman Dictionary says that *[**banquet**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/banquet)* is a formal dinner

> 1. a formal **dinner** for many people on an important occasion
> 2. a large and impressive meal

[*Macmillan*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/banquet) and *[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/banquet)* say that a *banquet* is a formal meal

> - a formal **meal** prepared for a large number of people on an important occasion
> - An elaborate and formal evening **meal** for many people, often followed by speeches.

Does "Banquet" refer only to dinner or extensively to a meal?

I want to receive an answer to my question.

Comment: It would usually be a dinner, because formal breakfasts, lunches and suppers are rarely held.

Comment: Note that the meal called *dinner*, i.e. the most substantial of the day, is eaten midday in some parts of the English-speaking world (and the evening meal is *supper*) and in the evening in other parts (and the midday meal is *lunch* or *luncheon*). See e.g. *[“Lunch” vs. “dinner” vs. “supper” — times and meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22446)*

Comment: Depends on how you define *dinner*. More research, please.

Comment: Google images gives you an idea of what a banquet looks like https://www.google.com/search?q=banquet&num=20&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwpI_lucTdAhWs4YUKHT8OARkQ_AUIDigB&biw=1309&bih=647

Comment: the meals can be less opulent ... many times it is a banquet because of fortune, grace etc.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionaries don't necessarily disagree.

Look at the Longman Dictionary's first definition of [dinner](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/dinner):

> 1. the main meal of the day, eaten in the middle of the day or the evening.

A banquet is almost certainly going to be the main meal of the day. So if you use the Longman's Dictionary definition for *dinner*, a *banquet* could be held either in the middle of the day or in the evening.

Comment: Indeed, for *banquet* the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/15298?rskey=saAckB&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) has, amongst other things: *A feast, a sumptuous entertainment of food and drink; now usually a ceremonial or state feast, followed by speeches.* Notice how it does not mention “dinner” explicitly. One can easily imagine a banquet served after a wedding or graduation, no matter the time of day.

Answer (score 1):

a **banquet**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/banquet)

> a ceremonial dinner party for many people; a celebratory reunion feast; a meal that is well prepared and
>   greatly enjoyed.

A banquet can refer to dinners, feasts ... and **any** meal at any time, "**well prepared and greatly enjoyed**".

Even breakfast:

> At a **breakfast banquet** in Universal City that same Saturday, De
>   León touted a landmark bill that he passed to cut California’s carbon
>   emissions. Los Angeles Times Aug 16, 2018

Comment: So does 'banquet' work by itself for a mining meal or is the qualifier 'breakfast' necessary?

Comment: mining meal? ..

Comment: Oops. Phone typing. Mining-> morning

Comment: a banquet at sunrise, after a meeting, at 7 am etc ...

Comment: You are correct:  A "banquet" is a fancy meal, usually served from a "banquet table", with a somewhat pretentious presentation:  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22breakfast%20banquet%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1986,cd_max:1994&lr=lang_en

Comment: @lbf I'm asking you to elaborate in you answer, in order to have it address what the OP wants, whether 'banquet' _by itself_ works for a morning meal, or if one needs to add a qualifier.  That is, would your given quote work if it were "At a banquet in Universal City that same Saturday"? Would people be surprised if, without the 'breakfast' qualification, they discovered afterwards the banquet occurred at 7am?

Comment: If a banquet was announced the person attending would then seek out its time.